# Call to undefined method AMQPConnection::channel()

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have installed the latest version og php-amqp but i cant seem to use the method `channel()`. This is the code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;


$cnn = new AMQPConnection();

// set the login details
$cnn->setLogin('guest');
$cnn->setPassword('guest');

if ($cnn->connect()) {
    echo "Established a connection to the broker";
}
else {
    echo "Cannot connect to the broker";
}

$channel = $cnn->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('email_queue', false, false, false, false);

$data = 'lorem ipsum';

$msg = new AMQPMessage($data, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'email_queue');

?>
```

and this is what i get

> Established a connection to the broker 
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error:
>   Call to undefined method AMQPConnection::channel() in
>   /var/www/html/rabbit.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/rabbit.php on line 26

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;


$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$cnn = new AMQPConnection();

$channel = $connection->channel();


if ($cnn->connect()) {
    echo "Established a connection to the broker";
}
else {
    echo "Cannot connect to the broker";
}


$channel->queue_declare('rand', false, false, false, false);

$data = rand(35,887);

$msg = new AMQPMessage($data, array('delivery_mode' => 2));
$channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'rand');

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```